# VBA Excel MacOs. Кодировка кириллицы при получении строки с PHP сервера

Tags: php, кодировка, macos, vba

Отправляю GET запрос на сервер, в ответ получаю строку.
В екселе под виндой всё работает. А в екселе под MacOs выдаёт кракозябры. Причём, только заглавные буквы ломает, маленькие получает нормально.

**Код PHP на сервере:**

```
<?php
header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" ); 
// charset=windows-1251 пробовал, utf-16, ISO разные, на эту строку вообще не реагирует
$str = "ABCdef.АБВГД.абвгд";
//перед выводом пробовал разные танцы с бубном, результаты такие:
//echo $str;                                                //  ABCdef.–Р–С–Т–У–Ф.–∞–±–≤–≥–і
//echo iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $str);                //  ABCdef.јЅ¬√ƒ.абвгд
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, "windows-1251", "utf-8" );   //  ABCdef.јЅ¬√ƒ.абвгд
?>
```

**VBA макрос:**

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function popen Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String, ByVal mode As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function pclose Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" (ByVal file As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function fread Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" (ByVal outStr As String, ByVal size As LongPtr, ByVal items As LongPtr, ByVal stream As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function feof Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" (ByVal file As LongPtr) As LongPtr

   #If Mac Then
    'макрос для Mac
    params = "test=test"
    result = HTTPGet("http://f0106330.xsph.ru/test.php", params)
   #Else
    'макрос для Win
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    comp = CreateObject("WScript.Network").ComputerName
    sUrl = "http://f0106330.xsph.ru/test.php?test=test"
    oHttp.Open "GET", sUrl, False
    oHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    oHttp.Send ("")
    result = oHttp.ResponseText
   #End If

Function HTTPGet(sUrl As String, sQuery As String) As String
    Dim sCmd As String
    Dim sResult As String
    Dim lExitCode As Long
    
    sCmd = "curl --get -d """ & sQuery & """" & " " & sUrl
    sResult = execShell(sCmd, lExitCode)
    HTTPGet = sResult
End Function

Function execShell(command As String, Optional ByRef exitCode As Long) As String
    Dim file As LongPtr
    file = popen(command, "r")

    If file = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    While feof(file) = 0
        Dim chunk As String
        Dim read As Long
        chunk = Space(50)
        read = fread(chunk, 1, Len(chunk) - 1, file)
        If read > 0 Then
            chunk = Left$(chunk, read)
            execShell = execShell & chunk
        End If
    Wend

    exitCode = pclose(file)
End Function
```

А если выполнить просто `curl http://f0106330.xsph.ru/test.php` в терминале с минимальным кодом PHP на сервере `<?php $str = "ABCdef.АБВГД.абвгд"; echo $str;?>`, результат нормально возвращает.

Comment: Да, есть такое. МАС не любит кириллицу. Попробуйте после получения строки сразу выгрузить ее в ячейку. Сомнительная догадка, но, возможно, текст еще не попадет под влияние редактора VBA MAC.

Comment: @vikttur, сделал `MsgBox sResult` в конце функции `HTTPGet`. Всё равно `ABCdef.јЅ¬√ƒ.абвгд`. Подскажи, как из `execShell` выдернуть данные в бинарном виде. Мож нарисую свой конвертер

Comment: Нe в *MsgBox* (это ведь тоже в *VBA*), а на лист, в любую ячейку. Если нет, то нет. Отрицательный результат - тоже результат.  `Cells(1,1).Value = execShell(sCmd, lExitCode)`

Comment: @vikttur, сделал вывод в ячейку, та же строка пишется `ABCdef.јЅ¬√ƒ.абвгд`

Comment: Значит, не поможет... Как вывести в двоичном формате, не знаю

Comment: а если выполнить просто `curl http://f0106330.xsph.ru/test.php` в терминале с минимальным примером `<?php $str = "ABCdef.АБВГД.абвгд"; echo $str; ?>` ? Результат нормально возвращает?

Comment: @schmidt9, в терминале нормальная строка пришла `ABCdef.АБВГД.абвгд`

Comment: Попробовал вставить `sCmd = "curl http://f0106330.xsph.ru/test.php"` в макрос, пришло `ABCdef.–Р–С–Т–У–Ф.–∞–±–≤–≥–і`

Comment: @schmidt9, дописал вашу строку в вопрос.

Comment: @DrMcSheen я подозреваю, что дело во внутренней кодировке строк в макросах VBA, возможно связано с нормализацией юникода на макоси или с кодировкой, ссылки которые могут вас натолкнуть на решение: https://francescofoti.com/2020/01/solving-the-unicode-utf8-utf16-and-text-files-conundrum-in-vba/, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83935/unicode-normalization-for-filenames-and-copied-text-from-pdfs, в любом случае я попробовал сохранить результат запроса в текстовой файл, и там все норм

Comment: ваш вопрос интересный, возможно если будет время, я попробую в нем подробнее разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в кодировке, на маке в макросах VBA в данном случае используется [MacCyrillic](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacCyrillic), это однобайтная кодировка, а русский текст здесь приходит в двухбайтной UTF-8.

Например буква `б`, имеющая код в UTF-8 `D0 B1`, в MacCyrillic превращается в `–±` (`–` это `D0`, `±` это `B1`).

Поэтому в скрипте перед отдачей конвертируем UTF-8 в MacCyrillic для макос, для определения можно передавать параметр

```
<?php
$str = "ABCdef.АБВГД.абвгд";

if ($_GET['os'] === 'macos') {
    echo iconv('utf-8', 'MacCyrillic', $str);
} else {
    echo $str;
}
?>
```

```
Sub DoQuery()
    Dim result As String
    Dim params As String
    params = "os=macos"
    result = HTTPGet("http://192.168.64.3/test/test.php", params)
    Cells(1, 1).Value = result
    MsgBox result
End Sub
```

Однако это решение работает только для английских и кириллических символов, например это не сработает для строки наподобие `ßååååå` (вернется пустая строка), универсального решения мне придумать не удалось.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Ато я уж свой конвертер думал писать.